What classes, feats, or abilities lets you have advantage on attacks at the start of your turn?
I'm working on a wizard build using Jim's Magic Missile, and to reduce the chances of a nat 1 I'm trying to think of ways to gain advantage on the spell attacks. However there are some caveats I need to address:

Must be able to have advantage on the first turn, not the second turn.

Must be able to apply advantage on all the spell attacks, not just the first one.

Is generally consistent (i.e. doesn't rely on always catching the enemy by surprise).

If I have to multiclass, no more than 3 levels.


For example, I've considered the Assassination feature from Assassin, since it does this:

Starting at 3rd level, you are at your deadliest when you get the drop
on your enemies. You have advantage on attack rolls against any
creature that hasn't taken a turn in the combat yet. In addition, any
hit you score against a creature that is surprised is a critical hit.

It fulfills all four criteria, since it works on turn one, will apply to all attack rolls, being able to act before the enemy is easy enough with the build I have in mind, and I only need 3 levels in rogue. That being said I'm looking for other ways to do something similar as well.

Assassin only works on the first turn not the second, so doesn't meet the consistent requirements, unless I am reading them wrong.

Why not just use Greater Invisibility? No multiclassing required.

Say hello to my little friend: Pack Tactics
It's a Kobold racial trait, so it's not without its costs (and your DM will have to agree to use the Volo's version), but:

Pack Tactics. You have advantage on an attack roll against a creature if at least one of your allies is within 5 feet of the creature and the ally isn't incapacitated.

It'll only work if you Jim's magic missile enemies who are engaged in melee with another party member, however.

I’ve got some lengthy commentary here about how pack tactics is a potentially problematic feature at the table.

Good shout! :) ...had forgotten about this.

Pack tactics is a Kobold racial trait - rather than "Allow me to introduce you to Pack Tactics", this post really should be titled "Say Hello to my Little Friend"

@Kirt that was too good not to add.

Probably worth pointing out, especially since technically Volo's is "legacy", this trait is still official under the 2014 PHB's Barbarian subclass, Path of the Totem Warrior, 3rd level Wolf trait, but only works for melee.

Not strictly advantage, but Lucky
since you say

to reduce the chances of a nat 1

The halfling's lucky trait would help,

Lucky. When you roll a 1 on the d20 for an attack roll, ability check, or saving throw, you can reroll the die and must use the new roll.

It doesn't meet your express requirements, but it does give you the reroll any time you roll a 1, decreasing your chances from 1 in 20 to 1 in 400 of rolling a natural 1 on any attack, saving throw or ability check.

Lucky feat stacks with this for a total of 1 in 8000.

@order if, by that comment, you mean adding another d20, sure, but this solution was offered instead of advantage or other similar features, since it isn't resource based and is functionally always on. It does not provide the other benefits, but does make the roll of a natural 1 twenty times less likely.

Two levels of Fighter for Action Surge, plus greater invisibility
Action Surge allows you to cast two spells in one turn, as long as neither of them has a casting time of one bonus action. Use your first action to cast greater invisibility, granting yourself advantage on attacks against almost any creature. Use your second action to cast your damage spell.
Before you're high enough level to cast greater invisibility, you still have good options for gaining advantage with your first action with spells like faerie fire that require saves.
Generally, I think your idea of a Rogue multiclass might still be a better option, though. Cunning action lets you attempt to hide cheaply and gain advantage that way. My proposal can only be done once per short rest and uses a highish-level spell slot.
Some other options that need more than 3 levels:

Fighter 2/Warlock 2 for Action Surge + Darkness + Devil's Sight
Arcane Trickster Rogue 13 for Versatile Trickster (this is IMO the most reliable way in the game to gain advantage, but would take most of your levels)

Another option, of course, is to ask a teammate to cast greater invisibility on you or a control spell on your target, assuming they act before you in combat.

Take 2 levels in Warlock for Devil's Sight and learn darkness.
Disclaimer: Be advised this tactic is highly cheesy and liable to get houseruled out if you abuse it, especially if you routinely block and/or blind your teammates.

With 2 levels in Warlock, you get to pick 2 Invocations. Take Devil's Sight and another of your choice.


Devil's Sight
You can see normally in darkness, both magical and nonmagical, to a distance of 120 feet.


Learn the 2nd level spell, darkness. Cast it on your hat (you have to target an object or location). You will see just fine, everyone else sees a bowling ball of shadow.


Darkness
2nd-level evocation
Casting Time: 1 action
Range: 60 feet
Components: V, M (bat fur and a drop of pitch or piece of coal)
Duration: Concentration, up to 10 minutes
Magical darkness spreads from a point you choose within range to fill a 15-foot radius sphere for the duration. The darkness spreads around corners. A creature with darkvision can’t see through this darkness, and nonmagical light can’t illuminate it.


You will make all your attacks with advantage due to the Unseen Attacker rule.


Unseen Attackers and Targets
When a creature can't see you, you have advantage on attack rolls against it.

It takes a turn of setup to cast darkness, however, so this will only work on the first turn if you have forewarning of impending combat and manage to precast darkness.

Neat idea, but it won't work since the question is about advantage on specifically the first turn, and not the second turn (or any subsequent turn).

@Matthieu I tried to clarify that with my closing comment, but I will make it more explicit.

Why have you posted 4 different answers (2 currently deleted)? Why not put everything into a single list answer?

@Pyrotechnical I thought answerers were supposed to put different ideas into different answers.

@Pyrotechnical Normally I would agree; in this particular case, I think it was a good choice because each of the answers are fundamentally different.  The two deleted answers simply don't work, the one about darkness works within the rules but is not a good answer to the question in that it requires you to know there is an impending combat (and is scoring low), and the one with pack tactics works and is a good solution and is scoring high.  Each answer is being judged on its merits, whereas a single list answer might have voting that was difficult to interpret.
